# Flutter(iOS) -"No CupertinoLocalizations found", how fix it?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, localization, flutter-ios

I using TextField in my flutter  app. It worked on on  android. but on  ios  when I try to paste from the clipboard into the field I get the error:

```
 No CupertinoLocalizations found.
_CupertinoTextSelectionControlsToolbar widgets require CupertinoLocalizations to be provided by a Localizations widget ancestor.
The cupertino library uses Localizations to generate messages, labels, and abbreviations.
To introduce a CupertinoLocalizations, either use a CupertinoApp at the root of your application to include them automatically, 
The specific widget that could not find a CupertinoLocalizations ancestor was: _CupertinoTextSelectionControlsToolbar
```

[image]

This is part of my code, main page:

```
return Localizations(
  locale: Locale('en'),
  delegates: [
    GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
    DefaultCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
    DefaultWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
  ],
  child: CupertinoTabScaffold(
     tabBar: CupertinoTabBar(...)
     ....
  )
```

in each tabs I use this page:

```
 return MaterialApp(
 navigatorKey: navKey,    
 home: child,);
```

I have separate navigation in each tab.

how do I fix this? any ideas? I will be grateful

Comment: Now I realized that question is a possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55919047/10659482

Comment: You should not wrap with `Localizations` widget.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can try to add a delegate of `GlobalCupertinoLocalizations` instead of `DefaultCupertinoLocalizations` into your `delegates`:

```
delegates: [
  GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,          
  // DefaultCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
  GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate, // Here !
  DefaultWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
],
```

EDIT:

You may need to add `supportedLocales` too.

```
supportedLocales: [
   const Locale('en'), // English
   // const Locale('de'), // German, etc.   
]
```

Comment: Thank you, it working with GlobalCupertinoLocalizations